# How to get sum of a column in a table (for a particular employeeID) and store that in another column in another table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables, "Employees" and "Expenses"

Employees table has two columns "EmployeeID(PK)" and "Expense_Total"

Expenses has two columns "EmployeeID" and "Expense".
 Please note EmployeeID here is not a PK as one employee could have many expenses. I want to find the sum total for all employees and then insert that into "Expense_Total" column in "Employees" table, for each respective employee. How to do this? I've attempted the following below:

```
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.Employees emp JOIN payroll_system.Expenses exp ON emp.employeeID = exp.employeeID SET emp.Expense_Total = //I need the sum here//");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have try following query.

If you insert first time means you have no records in Employess Table than you can use this insert query to insert Expense total :

```
INSERT INTO `employees`(id,expense_total) SELECT emp_id, SUM(expense) FROM expenses GROUP BY emp_id
```

If you have already data into the Employees than you need to execute Update Query into the Employees Table :

```
UPDATE employees emp SET emp.expense_total = (SELECT SUM(expense) FROM expenses WHERE emp_id = emp.id)
```

Please try this.

You can check here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f4d67

Comment: Hi Hardik, thanks very much but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  Employees em
  LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
      e.employeeID AS employeeID,
      SUM(e.expense) AS totAmnt
    FROM
      Expense e
    GROUP BY
      e.employeeID) AS t
    ON t.employeeID = em.employeeID
SET
  em.Expense_Total = IFNULL(t.totAmnt,0);
```

Bye